# Accessing configuration value from another configuration in the Maven Release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Is it possible in Maven to access a configuration value from another configuration value? For example, in the Release Plugin it is possible to access the `project.version` key during configuration of the `tagNameFormat` element. What I would like to do is to then use the `tagNameFormat` value in another element named `completionGoals`. See below:

```
    <!-- Snippet from a POM -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
        ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>${my.pom.property}@{project.version}-${my.pom.property.extra}</tagNameFormat>
                    <checkModificationExcludes>
                        <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    </checkModificationExcludes>
                    <completionGoals>clean verify help:evaluate -Dexpression=${tagNameFormat}</completionGoals>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare</goal>
                            <goal>perform</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <pomFileName>${release.pom.path}pom.xml</pomFileName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Notably, in the above configuration, I can see that the `tagNameFormat` itself is populated with both the standard POM version property and my own custom property (that incidentally is runtime-defined at the command-line). However, when I try to access the value to define another configuration element, `completionGoals`, `completionGoals` appears as a variable placeholder, e.g. "${tagNameFormat}" literally appears in the resulting command. (Verified by running Maven with the `-X` and `-e` flags.)

Question(s):

1. Is it possible to get a populated plugin configuration value from the Maven plugin configuration in the POM?
2. Am I referring to the `tagNameFormat` configuration element correctly? How could I do this with the Release plugin?
3. What does the '@' versus the '$' mean? (Guess: Dynamically versus statically evaluated?)

Comment: Can you explain what you like to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to execute another maven command from within the `completionGoals` section of the Release Plugin. I want to feed it information about the release tag.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is to define another [POM property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties):

```
<property>
  <my.pom.property>...</my.pom.property>
  <my.pom.property.extra>...</my.pom.property.extra>
  ...
  <myTagNameFormat>${my.pom.property}@{project.version}-${my.pom.property.extra}</myTagNameFormat>
</property>
```

and to use it accordingly:

```
     <tagNameFormat>${myTagNameFormat}</tagNameFormat>
     ...
     <completionGoals>clean verify help:evaluate -Dexpression=${myTagNameFormat}</completionGoals>
```

Re 3.: AFAIK, the variable delimiters `${...}` and `@...@` are equivalent and I've never read or heard the contrary. But, to be honest, I've never ever used `@...@` since I'm used to  `${...}` from Bash and that's also the only one mentioned on the [Filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) doc page. (`@...@` is only mentioned at [Escape filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html) and such I didn't know that it even exists for a long time.)